# Black Flash Player Screen in YouTube in Firefox on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: youtube

I have been unable to view any videos online since the latest Adobe Flash Player update. When I go to view a video on YouTube there is only a black screen in place of the normal player.

Comment: If you go to http://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/ do you see the spinning flash logo or your installed flash version information?

Comment: I see the installed flash version information.

Comment: If you didn't see the spinning "f" logo then you need to install or re-install flash

Answer (score 0):

tried `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved with this:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/adobe
echo "OverrideGPUValidation=true" >~/mms.cfg
sudo mv ~/mms.cfg /etc/adobe/
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I found here when I needed: https://snipt.net/d1s4st3r/improve-adobe-flash-plug-in-performances/